# Getting Data from Halo 5 API - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, api, laravel

I'm working on the Halo 5 APi, I have successfully pulled data from the API, like total kills, or deaths in arena.
For more understanding of how I did that, here is the code. (Shortend):

```
class StatsController extends Controller {


    public function index(Request $request) {

        // Validate Gamer-tag
        $this->validate($request, [
            'gamertag' => 'required|max:16|min:1',
        ]);

        // Get the Gamer-tag inserted into search bar
        $gamertag = Input::get('gamertag');


        // Get data from API
        $playerStats = $this->getPlayerStats($gamertag);
        $playerArenaArray = $this->getPlayerArenaArray($playerStats);      


        $spartanRank = json_decode($playerArenaArray['SpartanRank'], true);
        $TotalKills = json_decode($playerArenaArray['TotalKills'], true);

        return view('player.stats')
            ->with('gamertag', $gamertag)
            ->with('spartanRank', $spartanRank)
            ->with('TotalKills', $TotalKills);

    }


    /**
     * Fetch a Players stats
     *
     * @param $gamertag
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getPlayerStats($gamertag) {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/servicerecords/arena?players=' . $gamertag;

        $res = $client->request('GET', $baseURL, [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'MY SECRET KEY HERE'
            ]
        ]);

        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        } elseif ($res->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return $result = redirect()->route('/');
        }

        return $res;
    }



    /**
     * Get a users stats
     *
     * @param $playerStats
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPlayerArenaArray($playerStats) {

        $array = [];

        $array['SpartanRank'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->SpartanRank;
        $array['TotalKills'] =  $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalKills;

        return $array;

    }


}
```

But Im stuck at were I have to get data for a particular **Playlist**:
So If I want to get data for a particular playlist, I have to specifiy a PlaylistID.

Here is a example call I made from the Halo 5 API website:
[image: Halo 5 API call for Arena Playlist]

I sent a post to Halo Forums  asking for help.
Here is the post [Halo 5 Post](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/01b3ca58f06c4bd4ad074d8794d2cf86/topics/how-to-get-data-for-each-playlist-in-laravel-5-2/9c43b259-56b2-4768-9ccf-23ade0f0c16d/posts)

[image: My Question regarding Halo 5 API]
I got a response from a person, but I dont know how to implement that response.
Here is the response:

> So sounds like you have just a small misunderstanding or learning to do with PHP. Your first line is simply a mix of array and object notation. So you are playing saying "In the $playerStats variable give me the Result array. Inside the Result array give me the first element ([0]). Then simply into Result -> ArenaStats -> TotalGamesWon.
>
> Why this doesn't work for your below method is because there are
>   multiple Arena playlists. At this point you can do a loop over those
>   Playlists and check the PlaylistId for whatever one you are looking
>   for and return that playlist. The playlists never show in the same
>   order so you can't rely on an array index.

I have tried everything, but I just cant get a Playlist ID so I can get its stats for that playlist. Maybe you guys understand what he meant when he said looping. I have tried for loops, and many other things. Sorry for the long post.